# Target Every Other Matrix Row

Tags: matrix, html-email

I'm using EE to light up a HTML email template, so, not surprisingly, I've had to resort to some trickery to get the layout working in Outlook.

Basically, I have a table, and I need a cell in the table to alternate between the left and right side for every other matrix row:

```
{my_matrix_field}
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="210" align="{switch='left|right'}">
        <tr>
            {if row_count:even}
                <td width="10"></td>
            {/if}

            <td width="200">
                <img src="{image}" alt="{alt}" width="200" height="200" />
            </td>

            {if row_count:odd}
                <td width="10"></td>
            {/if}
        </tr>
    </table>
{/my_matrix_field}
```

Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use multiple switch tags.

```
{my_matrix_field}
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="210" align="{switch='left|right'}">
        <tr>
            {switch='|<td width="10"></td>'}
            <td width="200">
                <img src="{image}" alt="{alt}" width="200" height="200" />
            </td>
            {switch='<td width="10"></td>|'}
        </tr>
    </table>
{/my_matrix_field}
```

Comment: It works! You should update your example and swap the code in the switch tags, so the top cell is even and the bottom is odd.